# jQuery selector using a string as context

Tags: jquery

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), I can see that I should be able to pass a context with a selector to restrict the selector to only matches within that context.

For some string contexts, this works fine:

```
>>> jQuery('a', '<div><a id="foo"/><a id="bar"/></div>')
[a#foo, a#bar]
```

For others, not so much:

```
>>> jQuery('a', '<html><body><a id="foo"/><a id="bar"/></body></html>')
[]
```

If I've got a complete HTML document as a string, and I want to use jQuery to pull elements out of it, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Per jQuery docs the selector context can be "A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery object".

Try this.

`jQuery('<html><body><a id="foo"/><a id="bar"/></body></html>').find('a')`

Or

`jQuery('a', jQuery('<html><body><a id="foo"/><a id="bar"/></body></html>'))`

Comment: uhm... none of those work.  I just popped open Firebug in this page, pasted them in, and they both just return `[]`.

Comment: Yep it is.  And there are no errors.  Did you try this yourself? What's it output for you?

Comment: `jQuery('<html><body><a id="foo"/><a id="bar"/></body></html>')` returns `[a#foo, a#bar]`, so it seems to be returning the children of body which is why your examples return `[]`, since none of the children of body in this example contain anchors.

Comment: Oops! yes you are right. May be in this case you would want to use `filter` instead of `find`. `jQuery('<html><body><a id="foo">f</a><a id="bar">b</a></body></html>').filter('a')`